# Cannot create schema migrations table in redshift with ecto

Tags: amazon-redshift, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a project where the database is redshift and I am using Postgrex adapter in my phoenix project, locally I am using postgresql, and everything is working fine, but when I deploy and try to run migrations, I am getting this error.

```
15:39:27.201 [error] Could not create schema migrations table. This error usually happens due to the following:

  * The database does not exist
  * The "schema_migrations" table, which Ecto uses for managing
    migrations, was defined by another library
  * There is a deadlock while migrating (such as using concurrent
    indexes with a migration_lock)

To fix the first issue, run "mix ecto.create".

To address the second, you can run "mix ecto.drop" followed by
"mix ecto.create". Alternatively you may configure Ecto to use
another table for managing migrations:

    config :my_service, MyService.Repo,
      migration_source: "some_other_table_for_schema_migrations"

The full error report is shown below.

▸  Given the following expression: Elixir.MyService.StartupTasks.init()
▸  The remote call failed with:
▸  ** (exit) %Postgrex.Error{connection_id: 5598, message: nil, postgres: %{code: :feature_not_supported, file: "/home/ec2-user/padb/src/pg/src/backend/commands/tablecmds.c", line: "3690", message: "timestamp or timestamp with time zone column do not support precision.", pg_code: "0A000", routine: "xen_type_size_from_attr", severity: "ERROR"}, query: nil}
▸      (ecto_sql) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:629: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.raise_sql_call_error/1
▸      (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1336: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
▸      (ecto_sql) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:716: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.execute_ddl/4
▸      (ecto_sql) lib/ecto/migrator.ex:633: Ecto.Migrator.verbose_schema_migration/3
▸      (ecto_sql) lib/ecto/migrator.ex:477: Ecto.Migrator.lock_for_migrations/4
▸      (ecto_sql) lib/ecto/migrator.ex:401: Ecto.Migrator.run/4
▸      (my_service) lib/my_service/startup_tasks.ex:11: MyService.StartupTasks.migrate/0
▸      (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:680: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
```

It seems that redshift does not support some of the data types that postgres supports, so is there a better way to go about this or can I, create my own schema migrations table with another time stamp?

Answer (score 0):

There are limitations that the driver cannot outcome, since the principle of working compared to postgres database differs, [here](https://hexdocs.pm/redshift_ecto/RedshiftEcto.html) is the documentation to the ecto adapter.

In documentation is stated:

> We highly recommend reading the [Designing Tables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Creating_tables.html) section from the AWS
>   Redshift documentation.

If you want to continue to use postgres on local, then you will need to create 2 separate repos and respectively migrations. [Here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.2.10/Mix.Tasks.Ecto.Migrate.html) are the commands you can use to migrate a separate repo.

I recommend however to get a dev instance of redshift and use it for development, since the method of working with databases like redshift is different and you can easily make a mistake.

Comment: This is a different adapter, this is redshift_ecto and not postgrex https://hexdocs.pm/redshift_ecto/RedshiftEcto.html

Comment: `It uses Postgrex for communicating to the database and a connection pool`

Comment: Yeah I am not sure if I want to add this dependency, when this project has not been updated for the last year.

Comment: it highly depends on what version of ecto you are using, the library has 2 files, you can take a look at them and decide wether to add it or no.